# Create a combined text file showing the date modified of each individual text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a few hundred text files in a folder. I want to combine all the files and form one file, `archive1.txt`:

- I want to add the individual file names to each row of the new file
- I want to add the 'Date Modified' value after the file name

The code fragment:

```
findstr "^" *.txt >> archive1.txt
```

adds only the name.

I found this:

```
forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime"
```

which seems to find the 'Date Modified' for each file, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two and create one file with the both file name and modify date.

Comment: `FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO ECHO %%G %%~tG`

Comment: sorry, I'm not very good at batch. I don't understand how I use this? If I use this as-is, this seems to just display the information. How do I add this to the file i am trying to build?

Comment: `findstr "^" *.txt >> archive1.txt` also only lists files with content, and I absolutely expect that a file without content to still have a modified date and time stamp.

Comment: Full batch file content example @CarloB.: `@(For %%G In (*.txt) Do @Echo %%~ntxG) 1>"archive1.txt"` _Please note however that if you are enumerating text files in the current directory, and outputting to another text file, that text file is likely to hold its own name within itself_.

Comment: @Compo: This somewhat works...the output file is a list of all the file names with the corresponding date. The output file is, for example 100 rows long; one row for each file in the folder. What I am looking for, however, is the contents of each of the 100 files, in one file. This would create an output file with thousands of rows

Comment: @CarloB. I was trying to provide a more specific example to your [response to Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933334/create-a-combined-text-file-showing-the-date-modified-of-each-individual-text-fi?noredirect=1#comment125397733_70933334), not specifically to your submitted question.

Comment: `(for %%G in (*.txt) do @(echo%%~ntxG&type "%%G"))>archive1.out`, followed by `ren "archive1.out" "archive1.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success is the [`~t`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) meta-variables:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\Path\To\Root\Dir" & rem // (path to root dir.; use `%~dp0.` for batch file parent)
set "_MASK=*.txt"               & rem // (pattern of files to combine)
set "_FILE=archive1.txt"        & rem // (full name of the target file)

rem // Change into root directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Write to target file:
    > "%_FILE%" (
        rem // Loop through all matching files except the target file:
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_MASK%" ^| findstr /V /X /I /C:"%_FILE%"') do (
            rem // Store currently processed file:
            set "NAME=%%J"
            rem // Read current file with lines preceded by line numbers + `:` to maintain empty lines:
            for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /N "^" "%%J"') do (
                rem // Store currently read line:
                set "LINE=%%I"
                rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!` and `^`:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Remove line number prefix and write line with file name and date/time prefix:
                echo(!NAME!:%%~tJ:!LINE:*:=!
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Return from root directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks that works amazing! exactly what I needed. I dont fully understand the first FOR loop, this part for     /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_MASK%" ^| findstr /V /X /I /C:"%_FILE%"'

Comment: You're welcome! Concerning the `for /F %%J` loop: usually a standard `for` loop (like `for %%J in ("*.txt") do`) suffices to iterate through files, but in this situation I want to exclude the target file `archive1.txt` (since it already exists due to the redirection part `> "%_FILE%"`), which cannot be done with a standard `for` loop; instead, I let `dir` return a list of files and use `findstr` to filter out the target file; `for /F` then processes the resulting list of files…